# Find Dimension of Array

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to count the # of dimension:

```
template <class T>
struct dimension {
    static constexpr auto n = 0;
    void print() {
        std::cout << "T is not an array: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T, size_t N>
struct dimension<T(&)[N]> {
    static constexpr auto n = 1 + dimension<T>::n;
    void print() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        dimension<T> d;
        d.print();
    }
};


int main() {
    int x[6][3];
    dimension<decltype((x))> d;
    d.print();
}
```

And the output:

```
void dimension<T (&)[N]>::print() [with T = int [3]; long unsigned int N = 6]
T is not an array: void dimension<T>::print() [with T = int [3]]
```

However, for some reason, when `dimension<T>::n` in the partial specialized template, it actually instantiate `dimension<int[3]>` instead of `dimension<int, 3>`.  What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How about drop reference and use `dimension<decltype(x)>`?

Comment: In `T(&)[N]`, `T` is not a reference, so later `dimension<T>` cannot match `U(&)[N]`.  `dimension<T&>::n` would solve the recursion, but might have other gotcha.

Comment: as @Jarod42 said, get the ref out. [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/q4YbGY4nh). also keep in mind [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) exists.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks. I think one solution is to declare another specialization template `<class T, size_t N> struct dimension<T[N]>` without the reference.  Kind of ugly.  Any better way to handle both (with and without reference) in a more elegant fashion?

Comment: Specialization `template <class T> struct dimension<T&> : dimension<T> {}` would handle all references. Or add extra layer and `template <class T>using dimension = dimension_impl<std::decay_t<T>>;`

Comment: @aradarbel10 thanks for pointing `std::rank`, which handles the unbounded array case while my solution doesn't handle.  Thanks!